# Faster solution to find $T^{*} $ from $T(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)=(0,x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $V= \mathbb{F}^n$ with the known inner product, define  $T(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)=(0,x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1})$.
Find   $T^{*} $

I did a standard procedure of taking the basis matrix by an orthogonal basis (e_i) and then i calculated the adjoint (since there are no complex values) of that matrix and i find that  $T^{*} = (x_2,x_3,...,x_{n-1},0)$

I wonder if there is an easier and faster way to find the  $T^{*}$, maybe by using the definition $<T(x),y>=<x,T^{*}(y)>$ i think if there is i would understand better the theory but i couldn't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; it's actually pretty straightforward. You can verify that this is indeed $T^*$ by simply substituting into the definition. It is also possible to compute (without having to make an educated guess as to the form of $T^*$). If $x = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and $y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$, then
\begin{align*}
\langle T(x), y \rangle &= \langle (0, x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}), (y_1, \ldots, y_n)\rangle \\
&= 0 \overline{y_1} + x_1 \overline{y_2} + x_2 \overline{y_3} + \ldots + x_{n-1}\overline{y_n} \\
&= x_1 \overline{y_2} + x_2 \overline{y_3} + \ldots + x_{n-1}\overline{y_n} + x_n \overline{0} \\
&= \langle (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n), (y_2, y_3, \ldots, y_n, 0)\rangle,
\end{align*}
from which we can see that
$$T^*(y) = (y_2, y_3, \ldots, y_n, 0).$$
The ability to compute adjoints without matrices can also come in handy when your inner product space (well, Hilbert space) becomes less finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the definition. Let $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $y = (y_1,\dots,y_n)$. We note that
$$
\begin{align}
\langle Tx, y \rangle &= \langle(0,x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}), (y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n) \rangle
 = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}x_j \bar y_{j+1}
\\ & = \langle (x_1,\dots,x_{n-1},x_n), (y_2,\dots,y_n,0) \rangle
= \langle x, (y_2,\dots,y_n,0) \rangle.
\end{align}
$$
It follows that $T^*y = (y_2,\dots,y_n,0)$.

The trick here, however, is making the jump from the first line to the second.